# query-replace-regexp on specific lines

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, query-replace

how does one do a `query-replace-regexp` to add a prefix string but *not* on EVERY line but rather just lines with text (or start with specific text?)

i know how to add a prefix with `query-replace-regexp` but that adds the prefix to every line (even empty ones).

Comment: Have you tried to use `^` to match the beginning of the line?

Comment: Is this `query-replace`, `query-replace`regexp`, or `replace-regexp`?

Comment: hi, its `query-replace-regexp`. i can replace using ^ but that covers ALL lines and i dont want to add a prefix in non text (empty) lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to approach this is to use `occur` to select the lines you want to modify, and then apply your modification in the `occur` buffer:

1. `M-x occur`, enter the regexp that matches the lines you want to edit
2. Switch to the `occur` window
3. Type `e` to enter `occur-edit-mode`
4. `M-C-%` to call `query-replace-regexp`, do your replacements
5. `C-c C-c` to leave `occur-edit-mode`
6. Move back to your original window, where the modifications you made in step 4 will be made.

This does the same thing that @icarus suggests, but uses two different regexps: one to select the line, and a second to modify the selected lines. This approach requires a few more steps, but might be easier if @icarus solution requires a very complicated regexp.

You could also do variants of this using `helm-occur` or other packages, but what I describe here works in regular Emacs without any additional packages.

Comment: great answer. I was going for *simple*, as the OP said he wanted to modify the *prefix*, so he needed to specify the regular expression anyhow, no matter how complicated.

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is the correct one for this instance. My answer is going to be more useful when the regexps get hairy. You can also use multiple-cursors in the occur buffer, which opens up different possibilities.

Comment: hmmm so i tried this but i cant get the changes made in step 4 to reflect in the original buffer. for example a word "page" which i want to replace with  "start". i search with occur, it opens a buffer, i change in the occur buffer (after pressing e) the words page to start, press C-C but nothing happens in the original buffer. any clue? what am i missing?

Comment: It should happen automatically, if you've entered occur-edit-mode (by pressing `e`). What version of Emacs are you using? This works fine for me on Emacs 25.1.50.2

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a prefix of `hello` to all lines which start with a letter, you can use `C-M-%` `^\([a-zA-Z]\)` `hello \1`

The idea is to use `\(...\)` to capture stuff and `\1` to represent the first captured group. Here I am using `[a-zA-Z]` to represent a single letter using the normal unix conventions. It would be better if I said `[[:alpha:]]` instead.

If you want to add the prefix to non-empty lines then the critical observation you need is that a line is non-empty if it has a character on it! So you want to replace `^\(.\)` with `prefix \1`.